# Inner shadow to create depth on image

Tags: gimp, button, depth

I'm using a sprites sheet on my 2D game that contains different buttons.
I would like to create other buttons with custom icons because I'm adding new features to the game that need a specific icon.
The sprite sheet is in png.

[image]

Screenshot shows part of the sheet with a list of buttons (Great work by the author) where I simply added two rows of clean buttons where I would like to put some custom Icon.
In this example I'm working on a bell which I downloaded in white png format, added as a layer, filled with a gradient for the first green button on the left.
What I need now is to create the inner shadow effect to create the cool depth effect like in the other buttons.
Do you have any technique to suggest in GIMP or other free drawing tool to create such effect?
Thank you in advance.

P.s.
*Buttons are small in the game so I don't expect to have the fantastic details of the original buttons; good enough would be ok.*

EDIT:
Thank you @BillyKerr, with your detailed instruction I made it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move and scale the bell shape on a layer above the original button
2. In the layers panel, engage the *Lock Alpha Channel* button on the bell layer
3. Right click the bell layer and choose *Alpha to Selection*
4. Select the Move Tool, and in the Tool Options hit the *Selection* button
5. Move the selection down a bit, hit *Select > Invert*, choose a darker green foreground colour, and do *Edit > Fill with FG color*

[image]

6. With the selection still active, do *Select > Invert*, and create a new transparent layer under the bell layer.
7. Choose white as the foreground colour, and do *Edit > Stroke Selection*, and choose Stroke Line, Solid Colour, and Line Width 1px.
8. Do *Select > None*
9. Select the Move tool, and in the tool options, choose the *Move Layer* option
10. Click and drag the white stroke layer so that the white pixels show just under the bell layer.

[image]

Comment: Just Wow, that's a fantastic result!

Comment: @systempuntoout Just one thing to note here, I didn't have access to your bell shape, so I redrew it using the Paths Tool, turned it into a selection and filled it with a gradient, which made a very sharp edged bell. Not sure the image you have for the bell will give such a nice result, but you can try.